# PhantomJS nuget package doesn't install .exe file inside .NET Core project

Tags: phantomjs, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I want to install phantomJS nuget package for my .NET Core project. This nuget package contains an .exe file (phantomjs.exe).
(C:\Users\.nuget\packages\PhantomJS\2.1.1\tools\phantomjs)

Building or publishing solution doesn't copy .exe file inside the bin or publish folder.

Do I have to add a specific configuration in my project.json to automatically copy .exe when I'll publish or build??

Comment: You can use a postcompile/postpublish script to copy the file or include it in the publishOptions include section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently PhantomJS nuget package (v.2.1.1) targets classic windows-only .NET projects; phantomjs.exe is included into 'tools' folder and on install nuget executes script (install.ps1) that adds 'phantomjs.exe' to the project with CopyToOutputDirectory=true option. Unfortunately install scripts are not supported for netcore projects; since PhantomJS nuget package doesn't include any managed assemblies, it can be installed for netcore project but 'tools' folder is ignored.

It is possible to use "script" section in project.json ("postcompile"/"postpublish" mentioned by @Pawel) to copy phantomjs.exe explicitly, but it seems there are no any acceptable way to resolve path to PhantomJS nuget package during build procedure. In any way, PhantomJS nuget package includes only windows PhantomJS build and it is useless if you planning to run your .NET Core project under Linux or OS-X.

Maybe it is better avoid using PhantomJS nuget for netcore projects at all, and create custom build script (executed with "postcompile") that downloads and extracts appropriate phantomjs build for your target runtime platform.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked for copying the exe to the output folder on publish:

```
  <Target Name="PhantomJsOnBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(NugetPackageRoot)PhantomJS\2.1.1\tools\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PhantomJsOnPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(NugetPackageRoot)PhantomJS\2.1.1\tools\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
  </Target>
```